# A driver is using 30% of my CPU, disabling or deleting it causes problems

Tags: audio, drivers, cpu

I installed Voxal Voice Changer because I thought it would be fun, and I was extremely wrong. Weeks after uninstalling it, someone told me my microphone wasn't working properly (robotic noises). I found the cause to be my CPU reaching 100%. I used WPA to find the cause and found it to be a driver called `voxaldriver64.sys`.

Uninstalling the program does not remove it, having the program installed does not reduce CPU usage, and deleting the driver (or disabling it with Autoruns) causes either my microphone to sound extremely low at max volume, or my computer to be unable to detect any sound input or output devices at all.

I'm not super tech-savvy, but any attempt to help is appreciated. I'd like to avoid formatting my system.

Comment: Have you followed the directions for uninstallation at the NCH site? https://nch.invisionzone.com/topic/31098-my-microphone-no-longer-works/, and https://www.nch.com.au/general/uninstall.html#AAA ?

Comment: The only thing I hadn't tried there was deleting the AppData folder (which I didn't know existed), but it just caused the "very low microphone even at max volume" version of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by deleting the installer. I have no idea why this worked, but it did. If you have the same problem I did, just do what DrMoishe Pippik suggested and then delete the installer if you hadn't already. It worked for me.